# Discord.js when you're writing a slash command file is it possible to return a value from it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Might be a stupid question but could you return a value from the slash command files in discord.js for something like a queue?

I've tried looking at the documentation and stuff can't find anything about it.

Comment: Could you explain your goal further

Comment: I'm trying to make a command to add a user to a queue in the main index.js file and then when you call another slash command it gets the first user in the queue and pings them (this is for a warzone 2 game queue my friend wants) and im not quite sure how you get the returned value of the username so you can ping that user later and add them to a queue.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you have data initialized in your index.js (your queue) and want to access it in a slash command. Have you tried exporting and importing your queue?

Comment: No, I mean I have an array in a slash command file I am trying to export the data out of it and use it in the main file where I can do something with it, I've already tried doing all the exports.etc module.exports stuff but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to create a module that will handle the queue. Here is a simple queue module that I wrote for you:

```js
var self = module.exports = {
    Queue:{},
    head:0,
    tail:0,
    addToQueue(discordid){ //Adding a member to the queue
        self.Queue[self.tail] = discordid;
        self.tail++;
    },
    getFirstAndRemove(){ //Get first AND removing them from the queue
        const discordid = self.Queue[self.head];
        delete self.Queue[self.head];
        self.head++;
        return discordid;
    },
    peekFirst(){ //Check who's first WITHOUT removing them from the queue.
        return self.Queue[self.head];
    },
    getLength(){ //Get length of the queue.
        return self.tail - self.head;
    },
    isEmpty(){ //Check if the queue is empty.
        return self.getLength() === 0;
    }
}
```

Simple require the module `require(DIRECTION/NAMEFILE.js)` or import it. You will be able to use the functions to handle your queue.